# How to disable "Error: Invalid Data" in trigger error message?

Tags: trigger, errormessages

I have a trigger in which error message is getting displayed in a standrad page using adderror method.Which gives an error

> Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data.

I want to disable this message and only need to display my customize message.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this error?

Comment: @DavinC yes!I kept as it is and added my error message below it.

Comment: Add your changes to your post and hopefully we can get it resolved for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple solution to my question :)

`if ( some condition) 
 {
   String errStr ='Error message';
   ac.addError(errStr);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(Session__c ﻿sNew : trigger.new)
{
   sNew.addError('Overlap Session');

}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation as to why this works differently, would really increase the value of your answer Anu.

Comment: Thanks Anu.It will give -Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data.Overlap Session.But this is not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/catch block around your DML:

```
try
{
  upsert someObj;
} catch (Exception e)
{
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message('some custom message', WARNING);
}
```

The Syntax isn't 100% correct, but I believe it's somewhat close.  If you are already posting messages to your page you should already know what to do.